# Why the website in my CefSharp not pre-loaded despite of initializing it in the constructor of the main UI Frame?

Tags: c#, user-interface, cefsharp

Here is my code.

```
public partial class MainScreen : Form
{
    public MainScreen()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        //Initializing the browser in class Browser
        Browser brow = new Browser();
        //Hiding the user control that contains the browser UI
         this.browserPanel1.Visible = false;
        //Adding the browser to my main form's user control
        this.browserPanel1.Controls.Add(brow.chromeBrowser);


    }
```

I have a button which has the function to show the user control that was initially hidden.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     this.browserPanel1.Visible = true;
    }
```

I am clicking this button after a minute.
Normally, the website should be fully loaded before I make user control visible again by the button click. But when I click on the button, the browser takes the same time as if it was created at the moment. Why is the website not pre-loaded into the browser?

//The Browser class

```
class Browser
{

    public ChromiumWebBrowser chromeBrowser;
    public Browser()
    {

        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
        Cef.Initialize(settings);
        chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://google.com");
        chromeBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you use CefSharp? I believe it must be ChromiumWebBrowser and not a Browser. Have you defined it as an alias for ChromiumWebBrowser in your using? It also looks like your code is not complete as there is no point where you do brow.Load(url) to say the browser control what to load. Can you please show how you do it?

Comment: @PeterLiapin Here is the Browser class. Sorry for the incomplete code.    
    class Browser
    {

        public ChromiumWebBrowser chromeBrowser;
        public Browser()
        {

            CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
            Cef.Initialize(settings);
            chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://google.com");
            chromeBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        }

Comment: It would be cool if you edit your original question and put that code there.

Comment: @PeterLiapin Done. Any suggestions now. Thanks

Comment: I have found the reason, please see my answer below. BTW, you can also check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54609068/visual-studio-is-not-letting-me-add-cefsharpbrowsercontrol-to-a-form-via-the-des/54610148#54610148 to see how you can use LoadingStateChanged event to add some kind of pre-loader or get notified by the browser when the URL is fully loaded. I guess that is what you are trying to achieve, are you?

Comment: @PeterLiapin Thanks for the suggestion too. This was exactly what I wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a similar discussion on github here: [CefWebBrowser display dependent](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/33)

The URL is not being loaded because you add ChromiumWebBrowser on a hidden panel, and browser never becomes created on a hidden panel (due too the fact that winforms creates controls in a deffered manner). On the other side, the `Load` method waits until the browser is created. But there is a special `.CreateControl` method which you can use as a workaround.

Taking the discussion on github into account you should add `chromeBrowser.CreateControl();` to your Browser constructor, so the Browser class should look like:

```
class Browser
{

    public ChromiumWebBrowser chromeBrowser;
    public Browser()
    {

        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
        Cef.Initialize(settings);
        chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://google.com");
        chromeBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        chromeBrowser.CreateControl();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million. This really helped me solve the issue!